# Require JSX in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How do you require JSX in React Native?

var MyScreen = require('./apps/screens/LoadingScreen');

Requiring a .js file this way works, but a .jsx file is not found.

Comment: The React Native team doesn't seem to be implementing JSX file support in React Native anytime soon. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2303

Answer (score 2):

I think you may just have to rename your file from .jsx to .js and the build process will take care of any conversion. Colin's answer would seem to confirm this.

An example of JSX in a .js file is shown in http://moduscreate.com/react-native-has-landed/ .

The React team continues to encourage the use of JSX: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html .

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved it with a quick hack:
open `[YOU_PROJECT_FOLDER]/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/DependencyGraph/index.js` and edit line 55 to look like this

```
extensions: extensions || ['jsx', 'js', 'json'],
```

the open `[YOU_PROJECT_FOLDER]/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js` and after line 333 add these 2 lines:

```
  } else if (this._fastfs.fileExists(potentialModulePath + '.jsx')) {
    file = potentialModulePath + '.jsx';
```

This will make the packager recognize `mymodule.jsx` files when you do something like `require("mymodule")`

*Note: the actual lines are from the latest 0.17 release, in other releases the lines may differ*

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but after a trawl through the source code it looks like only `js` and `json` are supported:

```
this._moduleExtPattern = new RegExp(
  '\.(' + ['js', 'json'].concat(this._assetExts).join('|') + ')$'
);
```

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/8b93b99d4a769f86fffc95d65434f2f6a3fd827d/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/haste/DependencyGraph/index.js#L68

This issue would seem to support that:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/231

Answer (score 0):

To work with **jsx** files I have to add `jsx` extension to the next file

```
node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/node-haste/index.js
```

in the line 148

```
extensions: extensions || ['js', 'jsx', 'json']
```

then change file

```
node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js
```

finally this in line 447

`} else if (this._platform != null &&
           this._fastfs.fileExists(potentialModulePath + '.' + this._platform + '.jsx')) {
    file = potentialModulePath + '.' + this._platform + '.jsx';`

and this in line 457

`} else if (this._fastfs.fileExists(potentialModulePath + '.jsx')) {
        file = potentialModulePath + '.jsx';`

This solution works for latest 0.39 version